# Django - Class Based Generic View - "No URL to redirect to"

Tags: django, redirect, django-class-based-views

I'm using the generic CreateView like:

```
#urls.py

from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from content.models import myModel

urlpatterns = patterns('myApp.views',
    (r'myCreate/$', CreateView.as_view(model=myModel)),
)
```

With a mymodel_form.html template like:

```
<form method="post" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

When I submit my form, the new object is created but I get the error

> ImproperlyConfigured at ...
>
> No URL to
>   redirect to.  Either provide a url or
>   define a get_absolute_url method on
>   the Model.

How can I specify the url to redirect on success ?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Have you tried passing in `success_url`?  e.g.

```
CreateView.as_view(model=myModel, success_url="/success/")
```

or if you want to redirect to a named view:

```
CreateView.as_view(model=myModel, success_url=reverse('success-url'))
```

Comment: That's what I forgot. Thank you

Comment: @Glide No problem.  The key was that `success_url` wasn't documented under `CreateView`, but under the `ModelFormMixin`.  Django documentation can be hard to get through sometimes.

Comment: Ok got it, that's right, the doc is really nice but there are so many concepts here... Not always evident to find things

Comment: @Glide It can take a bit of searching.  By the way, don't forget to upvote when an answer is useful.  Thanks!

Comment: What if I want to "go back where I came from", redirect back to the page that launched the create?

Comment: @NickAldwin How do I go down one level with the success_url?

I mean my post its at /blog/comments/new and I want to redirect to /blog/comments

Answer (score 23):

you can also try to define **get_absolute_url** in your models. For example

```
class Something(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='name')

    class Meta:
        pass

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return u'/some_url/%d' % self.id
```

Comment: this one worked for me when the main answer did not.

Answer (score 1):

Add in views:

```
def form_valid(self, form):

   return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Answer (score 0):

views.py/

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .models import myModel

class createView(CreateView):
    model = myModel
    fields = ['your fields', ...'']

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('some_url')
```

urls.py/ (of your app)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', views.createView.as_view(), name='create') 
]
```

Comment: Can you please explain why your solution works and why it is a good answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I'd advise against this naming. First: Your view should start with an uppercase letter: e.g. CreateView. Second: Naming your class createView would make it hard to distinguish it to CreateView.

Answer (score -1):

```
class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'
    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False
```