# Django Class Based Views, get_absolute_url not working

Tags: python, django

I bought and am Reading the Book Two Scoops of Django:Best Practices for Django 1.5  and in it has a example of Class based views. After this implementation I get the error after submitting the form.

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /NonProfitCreate/
No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model
```

Doing research I came along this problem [Django - Class Based Generic View - "No URL to redirect to"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6266415/django-class-based-generic-view-no-url-to-redirect-to)

I want the get_absolute_url to work in my program

this is my forms.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  npp/forms.py

from django import forms

from .models import NonProfit

class NonProfitCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NonProfit
        fields = ("name","contact_name","email","phone","address","image","tags",)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        return super(NonProfitCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['commit']=False
        obj = super(NonProfitCreateForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request:
            obj.user = self.request.user
            obj.save()

class NonProfitUpdateForm(NonProfitCreateForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NonProfit
```

this is my models.py and views files

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import permalink
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField
from django.contrib import admin

from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

import tagging
from tagging.models import Tag
# Create your models here.
''' this is for the Non-Profit Proccess '''

class NonProfit (models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True)


    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=128)
    slug = AutoSlugField(('slug'), max_length=128, unique=True, populate_from=('name',))
    tags = tagging.fields.TagField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("npp/nonprofit_detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})  

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_tags(self):
        return Tag.objects.get_for_object(self)




  # Create your views here.
    # Auction/npp/views.py

from Auction.views import ActionMixin

from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.generic import CreateView, UpdateView, DetailView

from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin

from forms import NonProfitCreateForm,NonProfitUpdateForm


from models import NonProfit

class NonProfitCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,ActionMixin,CreateView):
    model = NonProfit
    action = "created"
    form_class = NonProfitCreateForm

class NonProfitUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,ActionMixin,UpdateView):
    model = NonProfit
    action = "updated"
    form_class = NonProfitUpdateForm


class NonProfitDetailView(DetailView):
    model = NonProfit


# Auction/views.py
class ActionMixin(object):
    @property
    def action(self):
        msg = "{0} is missing action.".format(self.__class__)
        raise NotImplementedError(msg)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        msg = "{0}!".format(self.action)
        messages.info(self.request, msg)
        return super(ActionMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

urls.py

```
url(
    regex=r'^NonProfitCreate/',
    view=NonProfitCreateView.as_view(),
    name='NonProfitCreate',
),
url(
    regex=r'^NonProfit/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/',
    view=NonProfitDetailView.as_view(),
    name='NonProfit'
    )
```

this is my stacktrace, the django braces is highlighted, and

```
/home/talisman/projects/Auction/Auction/views.py in form_valid
        return super(ActionMixin, self).form_valid(form) 

EEnvironment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/NonProfitCreate/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.4
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django.contrib.comments',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'zinnia',
 'tagging',
 'mptt',
 'south',
 'misc',
 'adm',
 'registration',
 'npp',
 'blogs')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/Auction/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/Auction/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/Auction/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_braces-1.0.0-py2.7.egg/braces/views.py" in dispatch
  98.             **kwargs)
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/Auction/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  86.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/Auction/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  199.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/Auction/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  165.             return self.form_valid(form)
File "/home/talisman/projects/auction/Auction/views.py" in form_valid
  54.       return super(ActionMixin, self).form_valid(form)
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/Auction/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  128.         return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/Auction/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/views/generic/edit.py" in form_valid
  65.         return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
File "/home/talisman/virt_env/Auction/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.5.1-py2.7.egg/django/views/generic/edit.py" in get_success_url
  119.                     "No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define"

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /NonProfitCreate/
Exception Value: No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.
```

Comment: Please show your `NonProfitCreateForm`.

Comment: Why don't you instantiate the model in manage.py shell and call get_absolute_url on it.. from there you can debug with a stack trace.

Comment: You have a duplicate argument slug on your model

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This exception is produced because `self.object = None` when attempting to redirect after a valid edit.  Since the value of `self.object` is the result of a `form.save()` call, the most likely reason for this error is that you have overridden the `save()` method in `NonProfitCreateForm`, but forgotten to return the saved object.

The `Form.save()` method is expected to return the object that was saved and should not be `None`.

Your `NonProfitCreateForm` could be modified as shown below:

```
class NonProfitCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['commit']=False
        obj = super(NonProfitCreateForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request:
            obj.user = self.request.user
            obj.save()
        return obj #<--- Return saved object to caller.
```

The first two lines of your `save()` method will create a model instance from the entered form data.  But because `commit=False`, the object will *not* be saved to the database.  If `self.request` is not present on your form instance, a the returned object will not have a database primary key, and  `get_absolute_url` will still fail.

So, you want to ensure that a `request` parameter is always passed to your form when instantiated.  This doesn't happen by default, so you need to arrange your view code to instantiate your form with a `request` parameter.

Looking through the [code for `FormMixin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.1/django/views/generic/edit.py#L10) you can see that there is a `get_form_kwargs` function which determines the arguments to pass to any instantiated form.  You need to pass `request=self.request`, so in your view override `get_form_kwargs` to add the required parameter, something like this:

```
class NonProfitCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,ActionMixin,CreateView):
    model = NonProfit
    action = "created"
    form_class = NonProfitCreateForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        # Ensure the current `request` is provided to NonProfitCreateForm.
        kwargs = super(NonProfitCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({ 'request': self.request })
        return kwargs
```

It would probably be a better idea to create a subclass of `CreateView` with the modified `get_form_kwargs` function, and have your `NonProfitCreateView` derive from the subclass.

Comment: I think you nailed the problem, Unfortunately I only have a vauge understanding of this. I added my forms.py could you show me how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `reverse`, use the name of the url pattern you wish to reverse.

You wish to redirect to this url:

```
url(
    regex=r'^NonProfit/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/',
    view=NonProfitDetailView.as_view(),
    name='NonProfit'
    )
```

Therefore your `get_absolute_url` method should be:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("NonProfit", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})
```

Comment: For others' benefit, it was not obvious to me that the `get_absolute_url` belongs in the original model, on which the UpdateView/CreateView is based as described at the top of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/ (in the critical note 'Some of the examples on this page assume that an Author model has been defined as follows in myapp/models.py')

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `@permalink` decorator from your `get_absolute_url` method. It cannot work together with `reverse`.

Also, the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#the-permalink-decorator) states the following:

> The `permalink` decorator is no longer recommended. You should use `reverse()` in the body of your `get_absolute_url` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can override your class-based view's `get_success_url` function. Like this:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse("NonProfit", kwargs={"slug": self.object.slug})
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this for a `CreateView` (or any other view that inherits the `ModelFormMixin`) because the [`ModelFormMixin.get_success_url`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5/django/views/generic/edit.py#L108) method will try to call the instance's `get_absolute_url` to get the success url.

Comment: Although your point about url reverse is sound, it is not related to this error. The problem is `get_absolute_url` is not found. Your solution is for no reverse match found error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem after reading the first sentence of [Austin Phillips](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16651802/7728887):

```py
    def form_valid(self, form):
        article = form.save(commit=False)
        article.author = self.request.user
        self.object = article.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

the point is the save `article.save()`'s result back to `self.object`